# подключение java к БД c ssh-туннелированием

Tags: java, база-данных, ssh-tunnel

Есть БД с ssh-tunneling.

Через SQLyog и через DataTable в IdeaIJ к этой БД нормально подключаюсь. И мне нужно подключиться и выполнять запросы через java
шатко-валко написала такой код:

```
Connection con = null;
JSch jsch = new JSch();

Session session = jsch.getSession(proxyUser, proxyHost, 22);
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.setPassword(proxyPassword);

session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
session.connect();
session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, url, 3306);


Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("user", user);
properties.setProperty("password", password);
properties.setProperty("useUnicode", "true");
properties.setProperty("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://" + url + ":" + localPort + "/" + nameBD + "?autoReconnect=true", properties);
```

и вот на последней строчке ошибка:

> Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такую проблему можно решить?

Полностью логи:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3
>   times. Giving up.     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:718)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:46)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)  at
>   ru.gamble.stepdefs.CommonStepDefs.ww(CommonStepDefs.java:968)     at
>   ru.gamble.stepdefs.CommonStepDefs.confirmEmail2(CommonStepDefs.java:929)
>     at ✽.берем
>   "PHONE"(C:/IdeaProject/autotests/autotests-888-m/src/test/resources/features/registration-authorization/testORTAX.feature:16)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:244)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:280)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2177)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:718)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:46)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)  at
>   ru.gamble.stepdefs.CommonStepDefs.ww(CommonStepDefs.java:968)     at
>   ru.gamble.stepdefs.CommonStepDefs.confirmEmail2(CommonStepDefs.java:929)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Comment: Попробуйте в последней строке после ? добавить "useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow".

Comment: Попробуйте тестировать соединение.

Comment: Что лежит в `url`?

Comment: попробуйте изменить "последнюю строчку", используя логин/пароль: `con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, user, password);`

Comment: в getConnection добавила "useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow" и вместо properties использую только логин и пароль - к сожалению не помогло. ошибка та же самая

Comment: Во-первых используйте новый драйвер com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver. Во-вторых, я правильно понимаю, что ошибка у вас во время выполнения кода? Если так, выложите, пожалуйста логи полностью

Comment: Если ещё интересно, то в феврале я это делал так:
https://github.com/Bakhuss/SSHTestFromJava/blob/master/src/main/java/SSHTest.java